# converting a binary number to a decimal number without using lists

Tags: python

```
def b_num(n): 
    
    result = 0

    str_n = str(n)
    
    for j in str_n:
        if j == '1':
            result = result + 2**str_n.index(j)
               
    
    print(result)
                
                   
                
b_num(11011011)
```

This is my code to convert a binary number to a decimal number. I have input the binary number **11011011**which is supposed to give me **219** as the output. But I am getting only 6. Where have I made the mistake?

Comment: `int('11011011', 2)`? Without using any lists.

Comment: ``Where have I made the mistake?`` - str.index returns the lowest index in the string. not the "current position" that you probably want. Checkout [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Although your variable `str_n` consists of 6 `1`s and 2 `0`s, the call to `.index(j)` will always find the first instance of `1` at index 0. In essence your function is returning the count of `1`s.

Comment: look at the return value of str_n.index(j). Consider enumerate

Comment: Quick debug lesson: add this after the `result=` line: `print(j, str_n.index(j), 2**str_n.index(j), result)` .  Look at the results carefully.  Find where the results differ from your expectations.

Comment: Thanks so much. I understood my mistake now. Wish I could upvote you all